How to dsplay information whithin listview whitout saving it to database?
The problem is, I've got listview which contains events whaich are added and saved to sqlite database. For example there is a certificate added to listview which expires in 2 years 4 months and 20 days. I want to add this information without saving to database. The problem is my listview uses itemsource from sqlite database. I can't display that information without saving it to database, and also while updating the row with expiry date. And when I try to get to label which should display this information.

Do you want to add additional rows to the list, or do you want to display some additional data to each row that only exists in memory, not the db?

In thein same row information. I add row to database but int same row days left to expire shoudn't be saved in the database

you can use the [Ignore] attribute to exclude properties in your model from being persisted to the db
